# How to get list of boolean by comparing two list flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart

Currently, I am building a widget using Listview.builder

I need two lists. The first list that I need is the first List A. which will count the length. And the second list is the list of booleans

so for example

this List A

```
A = [a, b, c, d ,e]
```

and this is List B

```
B =[c, e]
```

and the result that I want is

```
C = [false, false, true , false, true]
```

but the results that I've tried return only True itself

Answer (score 1):

`map` should do the trick, but make sure to convert `B` to a `set` first since lookup is O(1).

```
List<String> A = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
Set<String> B = {"c", "e"};
List<bool> C = A.map((a) => B.contains(a)).toList();
print(C);
```

`[false, false, true, false, true]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
C = A.map((e) => B.contains(e));
```